# Get resource file from blobstorage and add to task in azure batch

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, razor-pages

I am new to Azure and Azure Batch Service. I created a simple .NET application that should run some code over a certain input file. This is how I started to create a Job, a Task and add the resource file that should then be processed by my application package.

1.) Create the BlobClient etc.:

```
        // Create the blob client, for use in obtaining references to blob storage containers
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = CreateCloudBlobClient(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);

        // Use the blob client to create the input container in Azure Storage 
        const string inputContainerName = "modelinput";

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(inputContainerName);

        container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
```

2.) Here a file placed just in the applications directory is uploaded and added to a list of resource files:

```
         List<ResourceFile> inputFiles = new List<ResourceFile>();

//upload the file that should be processed and add to resourcefiles
inputFiles.Add(UploadFileToContainer(blobClient, inputContainerName, "myinputfile.xml"))
```

3.) Create Batch Job and Task

```
    BatchSharedKeyCredentials cred = new BatchSharedKeyCredentials(BatchAccountUrl, BatchAccountName, BatchAccountKey);

        using (BatchClient batchClient = BatchClient.Open(cred))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Creating job [{0}]...", JobId);


                CloudJob job = batchClient.JobOperations.CreateJob();
                job.Id = JobId;
                job.PoolInformation = new PoolInformation { PoolId = PoolId }; 

                job.Commit();

        List<CloudTask> tasks = new List<CloudTask>();

        string taskId = String.Format("Task{0}", 0);
        string inputFilename = inputFiles[0].FilePath;

        //set the commandline 
        string taskCommandLine = String.Format("cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_DEVBATCHAPP%\\batchapp.exe {0}", inputFilename);

        CloudTask task = new CloudTask(taskId, taskCommandLine)

         //add my resourcefiles to the task
        task.ResourceFiles = new List<ResourceFile> { inputFiles[0] }; 

        task.ApplicationPackageReferences = new List<ApplicationPackageReference>{new ApplicationPackageReference{ApplicationId = "devbatchapp",Version = "0.0.1"}};

        tasks.Add(task);
     }
```

If I run the task now everything runs perfectly. However now I have developed a little ASP.NET Razor Pages App through which the user should select and upload a file. Since I can now only use a file stream to upload my file I had to change 2.) to something like this mostly following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/resource-files):

```
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            var file = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "uploads", filePath); 

        string containerSasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        });
        string containerSas = container.Uri.AbsoluteUri + containerSasToken; 

        using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await Upload.CopyToAsync(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var blobstore = container.GetBlockBlobReference("modelinput");
            await blobstore.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

            containerSas = blobstore.Uri.AbsoluteUri + containerSasToken;
            inputFiles = new List<ResourceFile> { 
            ResourceFile.FromStorageContainerUrl(containerSas, "myinput") };

        }
```

The rest of the code remained basically unchanged. However now I get a **BlobDownloadMiscError** when I try to run the task. When analyzing this in the Batch explorer I see that obviously the URL of the resource file is wrong, if I add it manually to the task it works. Could some one help me? How can I get the correct source of the resource file to add it to my task?

Comment: Please try to remove this line of code: `containerSas = blobstore.Uri.AbsoluteUri + containerSasToken;`

Comment: Please try to covert  the line of code : containerSas = blobstore.Uri.AbsoluteUri + containerSasToken; to string containerSasUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}", container.Uri, containerSasToken);

Comment: Had to rewrite that piece of code anyways, now it works...the new version includes Jim's version of the containerSas line - not really sure if this is the reason why it works now and where the difference to the original version is.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, you may not use the right permissions. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/resource-files). Besides, please ensure your storage account has been linked your batch account.

> For container access, you must have both Read and List permissions,
> whereas with blob access, you only need Read permission.

My code is as below

```
string containerSasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List
});

string containerSasUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}", container.Uri, containerSasToken);
var inputFiles = new List<ResourceFile> { };
var file = ResourceFile.FromStorageContainerUrl(containerSasUrl,"test");
inputFiles.Add(file);
Console.WriteLine(inputFiles.Count);

// Get a Batch client using account creds

BatchSharedKeyCredentials cred = new BatchSharedKeyCredentials(BatchAccountUrl, BatchAccountName, BatchAccountKey);

using (BatchClient batchClient = BatchClient.Open(cred))
{
    Console.WriteLine("getting pool [{0}]...", PoolId);


    batchClient.PoolOperations.GetPool(PoolId);
    
    // Create a Batch job
    Console.WriteLine("Creating job [{0}]...", JobId);

    try
    {
        CloudJob job = batchClient.JobOperations.CreateJob();
        job.Id = JobId;
        job.PoolInformation = new PoolInformation { PoolId = PoolId };

        job.Commit();
    }
    catch (BatchException be)
    {
        // Accept the specific error code JobExists as that is expected if the job already exists
        if (be.RequestInformation?.BatchError?.Code == BatchErrorCodeStrings.JobExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The job {0} already existed when we tried to create it", JobId);
        }
        else
        {
            throw; // Any other exception is unexpected
        }
    }

    // Create a collection to hold the tasks that we'll be adding to the job

    Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} tasks to job [{1}]...", inputFiles.Count, JobId);

    List<CloudTask> tasks = new List<CloudTask>();

    // Create each of the tasks to process one of the input files. 

    for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        string taskId = String.Format("Task{0}", i);
        string inputFilename = inputFiles[i].FilePath;
        string taskCommandLine = String.Format("cmd /c type {0}", inputFilename);

        CloudTask task = new CloudTask(taskId, taskCommandLine);
        task.ResourceFiles = new List<ResourceFile> { inputFiles[i] };
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    // Add all tasks to the job.
    batchClient.JobOperations.AddTask(JobId, tasks);


    // Monitor task success/failure, specifying a maximum amount of time to wait for the tasks to complete.

    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    Console.WriteLine("Monitoring all tasks for 'Completed' state, timeout in {0}...", timeout);

    IEnumerable<CloudTask> addedTasks = batchClient.JobOperations.ListTasks(JobId);

    batchClient.Utilities.CreateTaskStateMonitor().WaitAll(addedTasks, TaskState.Completed, timeout);

    Console.WriteLine("All tasks reached state Completed.");

    // Print task output
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Printing task output...");
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, the permissions and the linked storage account were in place....I ended up rewriting the whole piece of code. Now that it's structured a bit different it suddenly works, no idea why.

Comment: @Hatzegopteryx The permissions "SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List" can allow you to access containers. I think if you do not have the permission,  when you run "ResourceFile.FromStorageContainerUrl(containerSas, "myinput")" , you have no way to access containers then get blobs.

Comment: @Hatzegopteryx If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: but I'm afraid that your answer wasn't really fixing my problem, even though I'm not quite sure what fixed it eventually. I gave you an upvote but since my reputation is too low, it's not visible...